# Android error while connecting to Google Endpoints

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, oauth-2.0

I must say documentation for this is really confusing. I want to get my data from datastore and I receive the following error:

```
04-27 18:48:40.951: W/System.err(1678): com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 401 Unauthorized
04-27 18:48:40.951: W/System.err(1678): {
04-27 18:48:40.951: W/System.err(1678):   "code" : 401,
04-27 18:48:40.951: W/System.err(1678):   "errors" : [ {
04-27 18:48:40.951: W/System.err(1678):     "domain" : "global",
04-27 18:48:40.951: W/System.err(1678):     "location" : "Authorization",
04-27 18:48:40.951: W/System.err(1678):     "locationType" : "header",
04-27 18:48:40.951: W/System.err(1678):     "message" : "com.google.appengine.api.oauth.OAuthRequestException",
04-27 18:48:40.951: W/System.err(1678):     "reason" : "required"
04-27 18:48:40.961: W/System.err(1678):   } ],
04-27 18:48:40.961: W/System.err(1678):   "message" : "com.google.appengine.api.oauth.OAuthRequestException"
04-27 18:48:40.961: W/System.err(1678): }
04-27 18:48:40.961: W/System.err(1678):     at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:113)
```

I am using OAuth and I have defined my Android device in my Endpoint:

```
public class Constants {
        public static final String WEB_CLIENT_ID = "bvye4g73g7.apps.googleusercontent.com";
        public static final String ANDROID_CLIENT_ID = "biurgf8ery8.apps.googleusercontent.com";
        public static final String ANDROID_AUDIENCE = WEB_CLIENT_ID;

        public static final String EMAIL_SCOPE = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email";
    }

@ApiMethod(name = "listCars", scopes = { Constants.EMAIL_SCOPE }, clientIds = {
            Constants.WEB_CLIENT_ID, Constants.ANDROID_CLIENT_ID }, audiences = { Constants.ANDROID_AUDIENCE })
```

I have followed these steps to create my Android Client ID: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/auth#Java_Specifying_authorized_clients_in_the_API_backend

I don't get it. I have defined my Android client on my Google App Engine Application and set it's ID to endpoint. I don't understand what is not working. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Is your endpoint authenticated ? If yes, you need to authenticate your call by providing authorization from the client :
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/consume_android#Java_Making_authenticated_calls

You need to select a Google account into your Android application. It's necessary only if you make authenticated call by adding User in parameter of your endpoint method :

```
@ApiMethod(name = "scores.insert")
public Score insert(Score score, User user) throws OAuthRequestException, IOException {
  ...
}
```